# Apache Zeppelin - loading (importing) code from a different note

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have some common code I want to run with many different notes (with the same interpreter - python).
I want to write the code once and reuse it across notes (and clusters since my notes are stored in a shared location), but also be able to edit it if I need to, so I've been trying to either run the code from another note using the same interpreter and context and share back the results or load the code into a paragraph in the note I am currently working on.

The best direction I have looks like ZeppelinContext's run / runNote which are able to run a different note but will not wait for it to complete and so I can't tell if it finished running. Mostly I only define functions in this "common" note so runtime should be almost none, but sometimes it takes a couple seconds to begin executing the note, which I want to wait before moving on to the next paragraph.

Is there a way to wait for the other note to finish running before continuing in the current note? Or is there a way to do this other than these run functions?